# What's the recommended approach to store passwords/users used in deployments for Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

When creating a release of a build, the release contains all of the variables as they were set up in the system when the build was made, this includes global variables like deployment credentials (users and passwords).

A deployment for a release of a build made a week ago that's now being promoted to production is failing because the deployment credentials have been changed since last week. When rolling back the deployment this also fails for the same reason, the credentials are not up-to-date.

Is there a way to update the variables of a build or have variables that should be used only for deployment projects?

Answer (score 0):

you can define variables at Deployment project level, not plan

Comment: What if the credentials are shared between deployment plans?